# unable to save video using opencv in python with xvid codec and lepton camera

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save video using XVID as codec and .avi format but every time I get a file of only 6KB and I am not able to play it. I am using lepton 3.5 cameras.
How can I resolve this?

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_' + str(i) + '.avi', fourcc, 9.0, (160, 120), True)
```

Please find the code below in which I am using it -

```
found_device = None
for device in CCI.GetDevices():
  if device.Name.startswith("PureThermal"):
    found_device = device

    print(" found lepton device")
    break

   if not found_device:
    print("Couldn't find lepton device")
   else:
    lep = found_device.Open()
     ID = lep.sys.GetFlirSerialNumber()
     print(ID)

for i in range(1):
   cv2_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
   cv2_cap.set(3, 160)
   cv2_cap.set(4, 120)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 9.0, (160, 120), True)

cv2.namedWindow("lepton", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
print("Running, ESC or Ctrl-c to exit...")
while True:
    ret, img = cv2_cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Error reading image")
        break

    cv2.imshow("lepton", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: You do this using a loop or not?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include enough code for us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @AlexMetsai Yes I am using a loop. You can see the updated code

Comment: @JeffUK Yes I did

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding
out.write(frame)

as below:

```
  cv2_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cv2_cap.set(3, 160)
cv2_cap.set(4, 120)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')

out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 9.0, (160, 120), True)


cv2.namedWindow("lepton", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
print("Running, ESC or Ctrl-c to exit...")
while True:
    ret, img = cv2_cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Error reading image")
        break
    out.write(img)
    cv2.imshow("lepton", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```